# Spring sending user to a view when no view is being requested

Tags: spring-boot

I have written a book catalog in Spring.
It collects books (pdf, epub, mobi, ebook) from a directory, collects some metadata from them, stores them in a DB and then puts them in a List that is made available to my views:

```
    @Slf4j
    @Controller
    public class BookCatalogController {
    // == Fields ==
    private final BookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    public BookCatalogController(BookService bookService){this.bookService = bookService; }


    // == Model attributes ==
    @ModelAttribute
    public List<Book> bookData(){ return bookService.getBooksFromMemory(); }

    public static final File bookDirectory= new File("D:\\edu_repo\\ebooks_test\\");

    .
    .
    .
// Catalog Simple View
    @GetMapping(Mappings.CATALOG_SIMPLE)
    public String catalogSimple(Model model){

        log.info("catalogSimple method called");

        // This is adding the entire BookManager book list into the model.
        model.addAttribute(AttributeNames.BOOK_DATA, bookData());

        return ViewNames.CATALOG_SIMPLE;
    }


    // Catalog Detail View
    @GetMapping(Mappings.CATALOG_DETAIL)
    public String catalogDetail(Model model){

        log.info("catalogDetail method called");

        // This is adding the entire BookManager book list into the model.

model.addAttribute(AttributeNames.BOOK_DATA, bookData());
        return ViewNames.CATALOG_DETAIL;
    }

.
.
.
    @GetMapping(Mappings.LOAD_BOOKS)
    public void loadBooks(Model model) {

        bookService.loadBooksFromDirectory(bookDirectory);
    }
}
```

Obviously I'm not using @GetMapping(Mappings.LOAD_BOOKS) properly as you can see in the error below:

The error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [load-books], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [load-books], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

How does one invoke a method like I am doing but without Spring trying to redirect the user to another view?
I'm not expecting the page to update at all since I'm not returning a View!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click a link in your browser with a *load-books* anchor, your browser sends it to the server and waits for result, which causes your page to be reloaded. Once the request to a *load-books* endpoint reached to the server, Spring MVC handles this and starting to looking up an appropriate controller with its method. It founds `public void loadBooks(Model model)` in your case. When Spring MVC invokes the method, it expects to obtain a view name to resolve and return back to your browser. 
Since you haven't provided a View or String as a return type, Spring MVC used the endpoint's path as a view name (I'm not seeing your Mappings.LOAD_BOOKS constant, but it supposed to be *load-books*).
If you're not going to return any view back to the browser, you can annotate the method like that:

```java
@GetMapping(Mappings.LOAD_BOOKS)
@ResponseBody
public void loadBooks(Model model) {
```

which tells Spring to treat `void` as a response body.
But it's not preventing a page refreshing, you'll just see an empty page after clicking the link. In order to fix this you can redirect a user to another page by returning the following string (without ResponseBody annotation on the method)

```java
return "redirect:/path-to-redirect";
```

When Spring MVC sees this prefix it redirects you to another controller, but user going to notice that too.

If you really don't want to see a blank page for a moment, you'll have to use some JavaScript to perform AJAX request to the server when button is clicked.

Actually, it seems that you want to preload some files in a service by a given path. If it's all you want to do, you can use Spring's runners like that:

```java
@Component
class Preloader implements ApplicationRunner {

    private final BookCatalogService bookService;

    @Autowired
    public Preloader(BookCatalogService service) {
        this.bookService = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        bookService.loadBooksFromDirectory(BookCatalogController.bookDirectory);
    }
}
```

Spring automatically calls all registered runners when application is ready, so your code will be executed without having a user to visit *load-books* endpoint.

Comment: What an awesome answer! Thank you